# AngularJS UI-Router : Get $state.current from inside a component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-components

I am using AngularJS 1.5.1 with ui-router 0.3.1

I am trying to get the current state from a controller inside a component.  I need to do something in my component's template html based on the current state.  It seems, however, that I cannot "read" `$state.current` from inside the component's controller.

I have a `leftnav` component that is using ui-sref to load content into a view on the page, like so (simplified):

the leftnav component has a series of links like so:

```
<a href="" ui-sref="buttons">Buttons</a>
```

This loads a route from my "buttons" module into the `ui-view` above.

If I try to log anything about the current state inside the component's controller:

```
console.log($state.href($state.current));
console.log($state.get($state.current));
```

I only get `null` for both.

However, if I use the same inside the `buttons` controller, it works as expected.

How can I access $state.current from inside the component?

My component is like so:

```
 (function () {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('app').component('pbDsLeftnav', {
    bindings: {},
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    templateUrl: 'core/directives/pb-ds-leftnav.component.html',
    controller: function ($log, $rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
      var _this = this;
      console.log($state.href($state.current));
      console.log($state.get($state.current));
      console.log($state.current.data);
    }
  });
})();
```

as I said, logging the same things inside the "buttons" controller *does* work:

```
 (function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('pb.ds.badges').controller('BadgesController', function ($log, $state) {
    var _this = this;
    console.log($state.href($state.current));
    console.log($state.get($state.current));
    console.log($state.current.data);
})();
```

Comment: what `console.log($state.current)`  prints?

Comment: `{name: "", url: "^", views: null, abstract: true}`

Comment: [related?](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1627)

Comment: It has to do with the component.  If I remove the component and replace it with  a simple `ng-include` I can access `{{$state.current}}` from the html.  When the same html is loaded as a component's template, I get nothing.

Comment: @Steve your `ui-view` template gets loaded from component itself?

Comment: after years, i have this problem too.. angular-ui-router": "1.0.5", "angular": "1.5.11". I ended up checking the application state using $location.search().param :/